# How do I remove or change the 'Unknown' option from the dropdown of a BooleanField filter created using django_filters?

Tags: python, django, django-filters

In my `models.py`, there's a `BooleanField` named `cash`:

```
class Realization(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    patient_type=models.ForeignKey(PatientType, on_delete=CASCADE, default=None)
    cash=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    amount_received=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

And I'm using this `model` as a `ForeignKey` in another `model` `IPDReport`:

```
class IpdReport(models.Model):
    patient=models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    package=models.ForeignKey(Package, on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    approvedpackage=models.ForeignKey(ApprovedPackage, on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ctscan=models.ForeignKey(CTScan, on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    radiations=models.ForeignKey(Radiations, on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    discharge=models.ForeignKey(Discharge, on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    realization=models.ForeignKey(Realization, on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    lockdata=models.ForeignKey(LockData, on_delete=CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

I wanted to create a filter for the `IPDReport` data, including `Realization's cash` field, so I used this way:

```
class IpdFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    patient__name=django_filters.CharFilter(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), lookup_expr='icontains', label='Name')
    ctscan__rt_number=django_filters.CharFilter(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), lookup_expr='icontains', label='RT Number')
    package__patient_type__patient_type=django_filters.CharFilter(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), lookup_expr='icontains', label='Type of Patient')
    realization__amount_received__gt=django_filters.NumberFilter(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), field_name='realization__amount_received', lookup_expr='gt', label='Min. Amount Received')
    realization__amount_received__lt=django_filters.NumberFilter(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), field_name='realization__amount_received', lookup_expr='lt', label='Max. Amount Received')
    from_date=django_filters.DateFilter(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'from_doa', 'class':'form-control'}), field_name='package__date_of_admission', label='From - Date of Admission ', lookup_expr='gte')
    to_date=django_filters.DateFilter(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'to_doa', 'class':'form-control'}), field_name='package__date_of_admission', label='To - Date of Admission ', lookup_expr='lte')
    from_date_bill=django_filters.DateFilter(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'from_bd', 'class':'form-control'}), field_name='realization__billing_month', label='From - Date of Billing ', lookup_expr='gte')
    to_date_bill=django_filters.DateFilter(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'id': 'to_bd', 'class':'form-control'}), field_name='realization__billing_month', label='To - Date of Billing ', lookup_expr='lte')
    
    class Meta:
        model=IpdReport
        fields={
            'realization__cash':['exact']
        }
```

Now on the `IPDReport` page in my app, the field renders like below:

[image: filter]

In the dropdown, the default option shows as Unknown. Is there any way I can change or remove that completely?

Also, how can I add an `HTML class attribute` to this cash field under `Meta class`?

Answer (score 0):

Django Filter's BooleanWidget [inherits](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/main/django_filters/widgets.py#L155) from Django's [Select widget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/widgets.py#LL745C1-L745C13), which inherits from [ChoiceWidget](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/widgets.py#L612).

Unfortunately, `BooleanWidget.__init__` does not accept a `choices` argument, so you cannot simply override `BooleanWidget.__init__` and call `super().__init__`. I was able to resolve this by skipping `BooleanWidget.__init__` entirely in the super chain. Regarding adding a class to one of the form fields, this is [pretty standard in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs), and Django Filter doesn't obfuscate this functionality. I've included it in the solution below.

```
from django import forms

import django_filters
from django_filters.widgets import BooleanWidget


class CustomBooleanWidget(BooleanWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices=()):
        # remove the 'unknown' option here
        choices = (('true', 'Yes'), ('false', 'No'))

        # bypass BooleanWidget.__init__
        forms.Select.__init__(self, attrs, choices)


class IpdFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    # ...
    realization__cash = django_filters.BooleanFilter(<desired attributes>, widget=CustomBooleanWidget(attrs={'class': '<desired class names>'})
```